# Getting 404.2 Error when deploying Silverlight Business Application on IIS 7.0

Tags: silverlight, deployment, http-error

I'm getting the following error when trying view my freshly deployed Silverlight Business Application on IIS 7.0 on a Windows Server Standard server with Service Pack 2:

> HTTP Error 404.2 - Not Found The page
> you are requesting cannot be served
> because of the ISAPI and CGI
> Restriction list settings on the Web
> server.
>
> Error Code 0x800704ec

I've deployed this application successfully on my own desktop PC.

**Edits:**

To my knowledge, I am not using either ISAPI or CGI.

**Further Edits:**

I don't seem to even have a "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" feature in my IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you mapped the .xap extension to the mime type application/x-silverlight-app in the servers mime map?  See [Register XAP file extention in IIS](http://www.85turns.com/2008/03/07/register-xap-file-in-iis/).

IIS 6 and above do not have a default .* mapping, without it you get a 404.

Comment: yes.  But I don't have .svc. Do I need that?  I have a plain old ASPX page and it gives me the same error.

Comment: @Jordon:  The you have a plain old server configuration problem.  I suggest you ask this on ServerFault from an ASPX perspective (i.e., don't limit the scope to silverlight it isn't a Silverlight problem).